# JavaScript: Issue with single quotes and URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, odata, call

I have the following JS coding:

```
var myVariable = "material'";   //<- there is a single quote before the double quote!

var object = {
path: "/Data(Material='" + myVariable + "')"
}
```

`object.path` is building a URL for a service call and will result in this:

```
https://myurl/Data(Material='material'')
```

Of course this service call will fail because of the two single quotes.

What else can I do?

Comment: use \ to take out the special character so \'

Comment: What is the URL you need it to be in the end? If you need quotes you can try turning the quotes around. Single outside, double inside and see if that works. `var object = {path: '/Data(Material="' + myVariable + '")'}` unless you don't want any quotes, then just do `'/Data(Material=' + myVariable + ')'`

Comment: So you need to either encode it or escape it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should take care of it. Just replace all single quotes in your variable for two single quotes:

```
var object = {
    path: "/Data(Material='" + myVariable.replace(/'/g, "''") + "')"
}
```